# Convert large JSON file to MySQL

Tags: php, json, memory

I have a ~1MB JSON file that needs to be converted to MySQL. The file has close to 400 records. What is the best way to do this using PHP ?

If i try to add 400 records in a single pass, I either get the memory or execution time error. Whats the best way around this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try a multi-stage approach. Use `json_decode()` to turn the records into INSERT statements. Then you can use the `FILE` command in the mysql client to run all the inserts.